# customizing symfony2 form date field

Tags: forms, date, symfony, monthcalendar

i want to build an form include date field with view like this.

```
<!-- day -->
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>and so on</option>
</select>

<!-- month and year -->
<select>
    <option>jan 2013</option>
    <option>feb 2013</option>
    <option>mar 2013</option>
    <option>and so on</option>
</select>
```

the month and year place in same select box
just 2 select box in view..

how to make date field like that ??
thanks before..

Comment: what about creating your own type and using the date type as a parent?

Comment: @WouterJ Can you provide a literature or tutorials about it?? because current documentation is not so help me

Comment: Maybe you can get an idea here: http://youtu.be/Q80b9XeLUEA

Comment: @cheesemacfly thanks for the link. I'll watch it first :)

Comment: what about http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html ?